# cant fetch new post from database via ajax in every 10 seconds

Tags: php, ajax

I want to check for new post in database in every 10 seconds and fetch it and show it on homepage. the problem i'm facing is the query is again fetching those post only which are already on homepage...how to tell query to fetch above from last id for e.g if last post in database with id is 25 so how to tell query to fetch above 25 and show it. thanks in adavance

here is Ajax Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var autoLoad = setInterval(
function ()
{
  $('#load_post').load('load_post.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000); // refresh page every 10 seconds
</script>

<body>
<!--append load-post.php echo value here-->
<div id="load_post"></div>
</body>
```

here is php code of `load_more.php`

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');

$sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM post LIMIT 2 DESC" ) or 
die(mysql_error().' Error loading data.');
$num_post = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the number of rows

// check if there is data
if( $num_post ) {
//this contains data to load into a page.
} else {
echo '<p>There are no added post yet, please try to add to start   
sharing.  
</p>';
} ?>
```

Comment: Stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions, use MySQLi / PDO instead,

Comment: how to get last $id any way because i'm using while loop to fetch post

Comment: `load_more.php` or `load_post.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE id > $id ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

Here, `$id` is the id of the last post

EDIT

If you use datetime, then you should use

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE datetime > $datetime ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

`$datetime` is the last fetched datetime

Comment: Ofcourse, if you can provide the query the last fetched datetime & select the data greater than last datetime.

Comment: so the query will be like ?

Comment: @Sithu, why need limit if we are selecting all the new posts only ?

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava Yes, no need `LIMIT` if we want to select all the new posts at once.

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava i'm having one more problem whenever i comment via ajax it works but when i comment on second post page get reloads and no data is inserted

Comment: here $last_post_id=time();                                                                                                                                                                                                $msql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE time > $last_post_id ORDER BY time DESC "); when the ajax request and send for new post then all post are gone ...

Answer (score 0):

** Try this query  **

**it is get only last id of your tabel**

SELECT * FROM post WHERE id =(SELECT MAX(id) FROM post));